# How to fix Object return type using fluent interfaces and Generics in java

Tags: java, generics

I have implemented fluent methods with an interface. But I need to append other concrete methods keeping the original functionality.

I have extended the original interface and created others.

But I can't chain the method calls.
The return type is Object, but the methods are well implemented.

I don't know what type of object will be instantiated. It is determined at runtime. So I can't cast to concrete implementation, for example

```
PlainTextProcessor<TabbedFile>
```

How I can fix this?

Desired functionality:

```
// TabbedFile is determined at runtime. I only
// know that the instantiated type should implement
// the PlainTextProcessor interface.
PlainTextProcessor processor = new TabbedFile();

processor.method1(arg1).method(arg2).method3(arg3);
```

Code:

```
// Base interface
public interface DataProcessor<T>
{
    T method1(String classname);
    T method2(String classname);
}

// Concrete interface
public interface PlainTextProcessor<T> extends DataProcessor<T>
{
    T method3(String[] data);
}

// Concrete implementation
public class TabbedFile implements PlainTextProcessor<TabbedFile>
{
    @Override
    public TabbedFile method1(String classname)
    {
        ...
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TabbedFile method2(String classname)
    {
        ...
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TabbedFile method3(String[] data)
    {
        ...
        return this;
    }
}

// TargetClass
public class Processor
{
   private PlainTextProcessor processor;

   ...

   public void Dowork()
  {

    // Created via factory
    processor = ProcessorFactory.GetProcessor(param);

    processor
             .method(arg1)
             .method2(arg2)
             .method3(arg3);

  }
```

Comment: You might have to use reflection for this.

Comment: There'd be no reason to use reflection here. The only problem is the return type, which only affects the fluent-style statement. `p.method1(...); p.method2(...); p.method3(...);` works perfectly fine.

Comment: The declaration `PlainTextProcessor processor` uses a [*raw type*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2711488).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java you have [covariant return types](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/covariant-return-types-in-java) supported out of the box, starting from Java 1.5.
So you need no generic at all for your example.

```
// Base interface
public interface DataProcessor
{
    DataProcessor method1(String classname);
    DataProcessor method2(String classname);
}

// Concrete interface
public interface PlainTextProcessor extends DataProcessor
{
    PlainTextProcessor method1(String classname);
    PlainTextProcessor method2(String classname);
    PlainTextProcessor method3(String[] data);
}

// Concrete implementation
public class TabbedFile implements PlainTextProcessor
{
    @Override
    public TabbedFile method1(String classname)
    {
        ...
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TabbedFile method2(String classname)
    {
        ...
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public TabbedFile method3(String[] data)
    {
        ...
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just chain your method calls right to the constructor.

```
PlainTextProcessor processor = new TabbedFile()
                                  .method1(arg1)
                                  .method(arg2)
                                  .method3(arg3);
```

Once you've told the compiler "This is a PlainTextProcessor" you only have the methods defined by that interface available to you. This includes the return types of those methods, which for the interface, are generics.

Comment: I can't do that because I don't know if will be TabbedFile or other class. It is determined at runtime. I only know that the class should implement the interface PlainTextProcessor.

Comment: Can you show the code for how the object is being instantiated/used then? For what you showed, my answer will work. If the real use case differs from what you've showed, then I can try to come up with a better solution for you.

Comment: wait a minute. Please